# Emails generated by Googleappscript are skipping my inbox

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, filtering

I have a shared google sheet that when someone enters their info it prompts the next individual with an email that's automatically generated by the script. These emails prompt a dozen individuals and show up as coming from my email. This has functioned perfectly for months.

In the past week or so I've stopped emails have stopped coming to my inbox. The still shows up in "Sent" and also under "All Mail" but I'm not sure if that's just the "sent" message".  All other users receive emails normally. Also, if I change my target address to a different email it works fine. Basically, it appears i can't send myself an email.

I have recently started using email filters which I know is the most likely culprit in these situations. None of them currently use the "Skip Inbox" function.

I have no idea why these emails don't show up for me despite working for everyone else as well as if I enter an alternate email address.

Edit #1:

Below is the section of code that emails the next person. As stated it appears to be working perfectly because everyone else except myself gets an email. Also if I change my email to an alternate email that works as well. It appears the issue is solely when the script emails myself from the same email address.

Also, I noted that I was previously receiving emails. This may have been untrue. As a testing measure I previously "CC'd" myself with every email that went out so that I could track that the system was working well. You'll note in the code that my email address is stored in the variable "emailAddress2" and that the CC line has now been commented out. I may not have been receiving the actual email sent to myself before but actually only receiving the CC'd version.

Here's the code:

```
function emailNext (JustPickedName, NextToPickName, SelectedDate) {
// Function Sends emails to the next Person in the list
  Logger.log("Into Email Next");
  
  //Set all the Email characteristics 
  SelectedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(SelectedDate), "GMT", "EEE, MMM d, yyyy"); //Format the Date for inclusion in the email
  var StaffMember = StaffList.find(StaffList => StaffList.Name === NextToPickName);//Find Emails address by finding name in Emails Object
  var subject = ' You have a pick pending in the ' + ActiveWeekSheetName + ' sheet';
  var message =  
      '<p>Dear Dr. ' + NextToPickName + '</p>' + 
        '<p>You have a pick pending on ' + SelectedDate + '.  Please look at the ' + ActiveWeekSheetName + ' sheet.</p> <p> Dr. ' + JustPickedName + ' has just made a pick and you are up.</p>' +
          '<p>You can make your selection here: <a href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KE9S5S0Rxc5Ygs0z5muZWplDqDvnal2aWzb-Ei_QeGE/edit#gid=1296569906">GGH Room Selection</a></p>';
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: StaffMember.Email,
    //bcc: emailAddress2,
    name: 'PickListBot',
    subject: subject,
    htmlBody: message})
  Logger.log("StaffMember.Email: " + StaffMember.Email);
}
```

Comment: I have reviewed this documentation both before as well as now. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to adjust my question. There is no code for others to reproduce as emails are being sent. Also Im not sure how to make the question more specific. I'm left with that perhaps this is simply an inappropriate forum to ask this question. If that is the case I completely understand and will move on. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? Did you make any changes to your code? @LANCE

Comment: @ale13 - I appreciate the reply. I've updated the code with an edit in the original question. The only change that has been made is that I commented out the CC'd line as described. You'll also see my description that I may never have been receiving the actual email that was "To" me but only receiving  the "CC'd" copy.  I really presume this is a Gmail issue and not code. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: What are you receiving if you insert this line as well `Logger.log(StaffMember)`? Also what does `Logger.log(StaffMember.Email)` output?

Comment: @ale13 - thanks for the reply. `StaffMember` is an object to keep track of person specific criteria. `Logger.log(StaffMember)` returns -> `{WorkbookColumn=43.0, Name=SMITH, Email=JOHN.SMITH@GMAIL.COM}`.     `Logger.log(StaffMember.Email)` returns ->  `JOHN.SMITH@GMAIL.COM`

Comment: And if you create a function simply for sending an email to your address, are you able to receive the email? Is this your main email address or is it an alias? @LANCE

Comment: @ale13 - Thank you for the guidance. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me to just make an emailing function for troubleshooting. I've got it working now. The issue appears to be case sensitivity. Having the email in uppercase wouldn't work. JOHN.SMITH@GMAIL.COM does not work while john.smith@gmail.com does work. I'm confused by this since a google search suggests Gmail accounts and email addresses should not be case sensitive. I guess I'll just ensure emails are fully lower case in the future but this seems to be an odd error.  For completeness, this is my main email address.

Answer (score 1):

#### What you are describing might in fact be a bug.

Since this is the case, I suggest you check this issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180693529) on Google's Issue Tracker and star it in order to get any updates with regards to it.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and I'd also looked at that documentation but I don't think that's the issue. I'm thrown off by the case sensitivity but it appears quite clear in my testing. I turned off all my filters and manually adjusted the target email address. JOHN.SMITH@GMAIL.COM did not show up in my inbox. It does show up in "All Mail" which I believe is the sent version. This is the exact same behavior as if I change the target email address to a different email address -> Jane.Doe@gmail.com. Finally, when I change it to john.smith@gmail.com it appears in my inbox without issue.

Comment: Hello there @LANCE, I apologize for this. I ended up updating my answer! :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I've accepted your answer. I presume you've created this Google Issue Tracker event and it's not someone else?